# My json object turns out null and I can't see why

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

So I've been over the web looking for a way to send data from my js to my controller, and came across a seemingly good solution.

```
function syncDB() {
if (localStorage.length != 0) {
    var data = viewLog();
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Leads/RegisterOfflineEntries",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
    }
}
```

}

this is sent to:

```
public ActionResult RegisterOfflineEntries(string[] leads)
    {
        string[] splitLeads;
        for (int i = 0; i < leads.Length; i++)
        {
            splitLeads = leads[i].Split(',');
            var validFields = new List<LeadFields>();
            var fields = new List<LeadFields>
            {
                new LeadFields() {Value = splitLeads[0], FieldsId = 1},
                new LeadFields() {Value = splitLeads[1], FieldsId = 2},
                new LeadFields() {Value = splitLeads[2], FieldsId = 3},
                new LeadFields() {Value = splitLeads[3], FieldsId = 4},
                new LeadFields() {Value = splitLeads[4], FieldsId = 5}
            };
            foreach (var v in fields.Where(v => !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.Value))))
            {
                v.Value = v.Value.ToUpper();
                validFields.Add(v);
            }

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
```

Now, don't read into the code too much, cause the problem lies in the parameter of the ActionMethod. It is null, and I can't figure out why, cause when I use the js data elsewhere, I can read the data on it, but sending it over to the controller doesn't work.

Thank you!

Edit:
the object im trying to send is fetched from the viewLog method which looks like this

```
function viewLog() {
var localDbList = [localStorage.length];
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    localDbList[i] = localStorage[i];
}
return localDbList;
```

}

what I have is a localStorage for offline support and I'm trying to take the values stored here and save them on my server

Edit:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:59848/Leads/RegisterOfflineEntries
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:json
Origin:http://localhost:59848<br>
Referer:http://localhost:59848/Leads/Register
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:C8AD858A-EBA0-4A75-8D89-38956182F914
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payloadview source
[DAVE, DAVID, HAHA@MAIL.COM, , ]
0: "DAVE"
1: "DAVID"
2: "HAHA@MAIL.COM"
3: ""
4: ""
```

Comment: post/get generally expect a `key=value` name pair for the submitted  data. you're just sending over `value` (the json string). `data: {foo: JSON.stringify(data) }`, and then tell the asp code that your `leads` are in the `foo` parameter in the post data.

Comment: Didn't work.. also I don't think I can send a JSON to a method with string[] as parameter. Gotta change that and work with the JSON object, maybe it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the original problem was, never really solved it that way, instead I did it with an API controller so it can do it's thing smoothly in the background. Code below if anyones interested

```
function OfflineSync() {
if (localStorage.length != 0) {
    $.post('/api/TrackApi', { '': localStorage.length });
    var formatedList = formatViewLog();
    for (var k = 0; k < formatedList.length; k += 5) {
        var value = JSON.stringify([
            formatedList[k],
            formatedList[k + 1],
            formatedList[k + 2],
            formatedList[k + 3],
            formatedList[k + 4]
        ]);
        $.post('/api/Offline', { '': value });
    }
}
localStorage.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the exact format that `data` is in, it should be like this before stringification

```
var leadsStrings = new Array();
leadsStrings.push("string1");
leadsStrings.push("string2"); //etc
var dataObj = {
    leads: leadsStrings
};

data : dataObj 



function syncDB() {
var data = new Array();
if (localStorage.length != 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        data.push(localStorage[i]);
    }
    var dataObj = {
        leads: data
    };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Leads/RegisterOfflineEntries",
            data: dataObj
        });
    }
}
```

Did you mean like this?

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you mean.. Sorry, can you elaborate this a bit?

Comment: this question is about the format of your data not being properly converted to your `string[]` type, but you don't post what your `data` object actually is. Update your question to show what your object looks like before you send it to the server

Comment: did you mean to put leads: leadsStrings?

Comment: updated. its a key/value localStorage rep. but only the value strings are extracted. as mentioned above, it works in another method i use to display these values in the browser, from a string array, just cant get it to the controller in this state :P